# Как ограничить mysql по поглощению дисковой памяти?

Tags: drupal, innodb, centos, mysql

Приветствую всех, кого не видел! Сразу к делу. Перевожу крупный портал в `Amazon` с довольно мощной машинки:

```
Intel® Xeon® CPU E5-2620 0 @ 2.00GHz 
24 ядра 
32GB RAM 
1TB HDD
```

Особых настроек mysql/php/apache там конечно не было (ресурсов много, зачем напрягать мозги). Упакованный дамп mysql весил примерно 250m, сам хост - порядка 1.5g. mysql/php/apache уже поставлены, хост прописан и работает, но mysql постоянно жрет **дисковую память**, независимо от нагрузки на сервер.

Кеширование отключено: `boost` не стоит, встроенное кеширование отключено.

Сейчас постоянно приходится расширять `HDD`, как только на нем остаются 5-7GB. На данный момент `HDD` на 100g. Дальше расширяться не хочется, да и клиентам нужен бюджетный вариант.

Один нюанс: на старом хостинге HDD был заполнен на 254g и я не уверен, что эта цифра до последнего момента не росла. Т.е., если я выделю 300g, вроде бы решу проблему, но у меня задача уложиться по возможности в 30g :)

Кто-нибудь сталкивался, что посоветуете? Хотелось бы решить еще вопрос, как этот кеш почистить, ведь все начиналось с 10g.

Если важно, то расширяю HDD по этому сценарию: [How to Increase the size of a Linux LVM by expanding the virtual machine disk](http://www.rootusers.com/how-to-increase-the-size-of-a-linux-lvm-by-expanding-the-virtual-machine-disk/)

---

Сейчас зашел на сервер, и df уже показывает 54% вместо 94%:

```
# df -h
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_root
                       98G   50G   43G  54% /
tmpfs                  15G     0   15G   0% /dev/shm
/dev/xvda1            477M   68M  384M  15% /boot
```

при том, что сервер с последнего перезапуска ни кто не трогал. От du объемы не изменились. После первого захода на портал по IP'у картина измнилась:

```
# df -h
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_root
                       98G   17G   76G  19% /
tmpfs                  15G     0   15G   0% /dev/shm
/dev/xvda1            477M   68M  384M  15% /boot
```

Что за выкрутасы?

---

Да, после ребута у du/df цифры те же. (
 --

> Можно посмотреть, что там в кроне.

Сейчас ситуация кардинально поменялась: в du выдает уже папки с хоста, объем диска то растет до 70% то падает до 20%.
 --
Я это сязываю пока с нехваткой оперативы. В top'е наблюдаю один процесс `httpd`, который сожрал махом `30g` вирт. памяти (о как!). По всей видимости, он ее пытается свопить на диск, вот он и растет. Сейчас оптимизирую `httpd.conf`. Но при чем тут mysqld пока не понял (я ему прописал в `my.cnf` забирать максимум `6g`, что он и делает в top'е)
 --
**Выходит, на своп для `32gRAM` все равно придется обеспечить `HDD`, размером `64g` как минимум + следить за аппетитами apache?**

Comment: А там точно MySQL память жрет? Может, у вас что-то логи объемные пишет? Тот же mysql может все логи подряд писать (а не только медленных запросов), если настроите его, отсюда и рост места.

Еще один вариант - может просто база растет? )) А раз база растет, то и место занимаемое пропорционально увеличивается. Здесь вроде как проблемы бывают: если база весила 100 гигов, а ее потом подчистили, то сам файл базы будет продолжать занимать те же самые 100 гигов. Приходится дропать базу и заново ее создавать, чтобы реальный объем уменьшился.

Comment: 32 ядра??? ничего не путаешь? там всего их 6!

Comment: ддос атака, смотри логи апача или нджинкса, они растут как на дрожжях, когда идет атака, ну и искореняй зло.
ну и как вариант у тебя каждый запрос может писаться в БД.

Comment: Спасибо, про логи как-то не подумал, сейчас проверю.  
 --  
Проверил. Логи хранятся в `/var/log/mysqld.log`. он весит `10k`, а `/var/log` - `3.5m`.  
 --  
Не верю, что база может вырасти на `100g` за 20 минут. Я вот сейчас закрыл портал от мира и сам захожу в настройки друпала. База растет. Прибиваю httpd - база растет. Прибиваю mysqld - база не растет.
 --  
>32 ядра??? ничего не путаешь? там всего их 6!

Точно. Еще раз посмотрел: 24 ядра (4 проца, по всей видимости)

Comment: >ддос атака, смотри логи апача или нджинкса, они растут как на дрожжях, когда идет атака, ну и искореняй зло. ну и как вариант у тебя каждый запрос может писаться в БД.

Нджинкса нет, а в логах апача запросы максимум по 10 уникумам (посчитал IP'ы) ну и про логи уже писал - их всего `3.5m`.  
 --  
>Посмотрите какая база растет

Да, посмотрел. Размер `/var/lib/mysql` - `570m`, из которых `555m` занимает `/var/lib/mysql/ibdata1`.  
 --  

    du -a / | sort -n -r | head -n 10

Вообще выдает директории с максимальным объемом `1008k`.

Comment: Очепятался: не база растет, используемый объем **диска** растет, конечно же:

    # df -h
    Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
    /dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_root
                           98G   87G  6.1G  94% /
    tmpfs                  15G     0   15G   0% /dev/shm
    /dev/xvda1            477M   68M  384M  15% /boot

Comment: @mega, после reboot du/df показывают те же цифры?

Comment: Интересно...

Можно посмотреть, что там в кроне.

Если опять будет расти, то можно попробовать find / -type f -newer /tmp/marker или что-то в этом духе, сделанным touch -t TMESTAMP

Comment: @mega, если это и правда mysql буянит, то попробуйте посмотреть какие в это время запросы выполняются. Там может быть слишком часто выполняется копирование во временные таблицы на диск, отсюда и пожирание места.

При плохом JOIN\`е данные легко могут вылезти за несколько гигабайт. Особенно если одновременно выполняется несколько таких запросов.

Посмотрите куда временные таблицы пишутся и мониторьте размер этого каталога. Попробуйте "временные таблицы на диске" создавать на tmpfs, должно быстрее работать, отсюда может быть пиковое потребление уменьшится

Comment: swapon -v -s покажет где и какие swap файлы.

Comment:  # swapon -v -s
 Filename Type Size Used Priority
 /dev/dm-1 partition 835580 0 -1

 # df -h
 Filesystem Size Used Avail Use% Mounted on
 /dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_root
    98G 92G 817M 100% /
 tmpfs 15G 0 15G 0% /dev/shm
 /dev/xvda1 477M 68M 384M 15% /boot

и пока работает

 swapoff -a
 swapon -a

Не помогает. Пока работаю с таким конфигом:

 StartServers  4
 MaxClients  300
 MinSpareThreads  10
 MaxSpareThreads  20 
 ThreadsPerChild  8
 MaxRequestsPerChild 100

думаю, увеличивать нагрузку на http постепенно, жду очистки свопа.

Answer (score 1):

Используй find, для поиска файлов, которые изменились или были созданы за искомое время и сделай на основании этого вывод, кто жрёт место.

Пример поиска изменённых файлов в течении последних 60 секунд:

```
find /path -type f -mtime -60s
```

Для поиска созданных, используй ключ ctime

Comment: @PazitiFF, вообще-то ctime, это не время создания файла, а время изменения его метаданных (той, что находится в *inode* -- пользователь, права доступа, размер файла и т.п. См. [man stat](http://linux.die.net/man/2/stat))

Comment: Согласен про ctime, немного запамятствовал формулировку, но эта команда тоже верна, так как при создании файла, ему присваиваются метаданные, соответсвенно ctime так же найдёт созданные файлы. Прошу отписаться, если данный метод поможет решить проблему.

Comment: Насколько я сейчас понимаю ситуацию, это какой-то сбой FS. В `windows` все просто: своп лежит в `pagefile.sys` и его объем видно. Здесь же этого файла нет, или я чего-то недоглядел. Объем на своп просто вычитается "в уме". Т.е., пока я не сконфигурировал `apache` и `mysql` на разумные траты памяти, они уходили глубоко в своп. Как только выставил настройки - все устаканилось. Сегодня даже пару раз `DDOSил` портал (с `ab`), чтобы apache выделил побольше процессов, для нагрузки и процов и всей текущей памяти.